# Finding containing sets, within sets of sets

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Let $s = \{\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \ldots \sigma_n\}$, where $\sigma_i \in \Sigma$, denote a set of alphabet characters.

And $s \in S$ where $S$ denotes a set of sets.

Given a new set $s' = \{\sigma'_1, \sigma'_2, \ldots \sigma'_n \}$ is there an efficient algorithm for getting all sets, $s'' \in S$, where $s' \subset s''$

In other words, given a set of sets, is there a way of getting the subset of sets the contain specific set of attributes?

I would be willing to build data structures with search and update complexities in the $O(\log (n))$ range, $n$ being the number of sets - also I would like the alphabet $\Sigma$ to be infinite.

The alphabet size is not known in advance.

This seems like a pretty simple problem, I am however not able to get my head around it.

### **Example:**

Given the dataset $S$:

> $s_1$: {a,b,c,d}
>
> $s_2$: {a,c,d}
>
> $s_3$: {b,c,d,f}
>
> $s_4$: {a,b,d,h}

and the query string $s'$ = `{a,b}`

I would like the result :

> $s_1$: {a,b,c,d}
>
> $s_4$: {a,b,d,h}

The only sets containing the two elements.

Comment: What do $\sigma''_i$ represent?  What is their definition?  Are they defined to be an enumeration of the elements of $s''$?  What do you mean by $\{\sigma''_1,\dots,\sigma''\} \in s'$?  That doesn't type-check (the left-hand side is a set of characters, the right-hand side is a set of characters, so the LHS can't be an element of the RHS).   Do you mean that you're looking for an efficient algorithm to find all sets $s'' \in S$ such that $s' \subseteq s''$?

Comment: @D.W. I've removed even more of my sigmas

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are trying to solve is called PARTIAL-MATCH: given a database of sets, and a query set, find all sets in the database that contain the query.

The most relevant paper is one by Charikar, Indyk and Panigrahy from ICALP 2002: 
[New Algorithms for Subset Query, Partial Match, Orthogonal Range Searching, and Related Problems](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=684567)

That's on the theoretical side. In practice, many simplifications can be made if one knows something about the sets and the query. For example if $|Q|$ is small, you might be able to get away with an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).

Comment: My database it pretty large, and the alphabeth is extreamly large, making an inverse index out of the question.